# Client VPN Issue - Cannot Ping or RDP to any servers

Tags: networking, vpn, dns, remote-desktop, tunnel

this is my first post and I always come here for info but I have yet to solve this issue. 
I have a VPN client installed on my local machine here at home. I fire the client up and authenticate to the corp network, I now this because I get the "tunnel enabled" message. Ipconfig /all shows everything correct - I am able to see the correct DNS servers etc.

When I try to connect to a server via RDP using the name or IP I am not able to connect. It appears that when I complete a tracert my traffic is traveling through my home network and not my VPN tunnel.

I just tried to connect to the DNS server using the IP address and at the moment I am able to connect via RDP. I am thinking that maybe my router settings may need to be adjusted, are there any settings that I should be aware of? I just factory reset my modem this morning.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure the Subnet Mask for the remote end allows the whole remote network. Your remote end Subnet Mask is likely 255.255.255.255 . Change this to 255.255.255.0 so you can see the servers and other devices at the other end. That always works for me.